# OpenCV Wrap Crop

Tags: java, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and I need to perform a 'wrap' crop. I am creating a new `cv::Mat` with the new crop.

The image looks something like this (those black lines constitute a person btw) So the input is an EQR of a 360 degree frame.

[image]

Can this be done directly using OpenCV or should I compute the position? If that's the case, how do I stitch those two images together?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it always going to be split like this? if not, you most likely want to have some way to differentiate between the two scenarios. Vertical projection (simple algorithm for character segmentation in OCR) might be helpful for finding the "cut point". OpenCV `Mat` class provides means to get a reference to a ROI (a subsection) of the source image. Knowing the cut-point, you can create 2 ROIs for the "left" and "right" piece. Create a new `Mat` of the same size, and use `copyTo` method to paste the two pieces to this `Mat` in the reverse order (left on the right side, right on the left side).

Comment: You need to define the question a bit, Do you have the coordinates of the bounding box, Do you want to crop it along the orange outer boundary etc ?